# Magento Onestep Checkout: How to create customer before last step (place order)

Tags: magento

When a user tries to buy something, he goes to the the default checkout/onepage to create an account and place the order. He fills a lot of info, but if he does not finish the order, all the info are dismissed.

Later then, if he tries to buy something he has to go all the registration steps again.

Is there an option to avoid this situation or this is just not the way onestep works?

TIA.

Comment: Right now I am re-doing my checkout for this very same reason -- combined with the fact that the standard magento checkout flow is bulky and counter intuitive.  If a customer wants to "register" and then checkout, I have an Ajax registration form that pops up and creates the initial account. Then on the address step is "saves" the addresses via Ajax if the "use as my default address" checkbox is checked.  I am in the middle of building this, but it is a fundamental task if you are going to not allow "guest checkout".  It's a lot of work, but totally worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

To register customer while checkout in one step checkout the same one request.

Look at this code in Model Onepage.php

```
    if ($quote->getCheckoutMethod() == self::METHOD_REGISTER) {
        // set customer password
        $customer->setPassword($customerRequest->getParam('customer_password'));
        $customer->setConfirmation($customerRequest->getParam('confirm_password'));
    } else {
        // spoof customer password for guest
        $password = $customer->generatePassword();
        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->setConfirmation($password);
        // set NOT LOGGED IN group id explicitly,
        // otherwise copyFieldset('customer_account', 'to_quote') will fill it with default group id value
        $customer->setGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
    }
```

So You can do in your custom module

```
$quote->setCheckoutMethod(Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::METHOD_REGISTER);
```